# Managing nested Firebase realtime DB queries with await/async

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I'm writing a Firebase function ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/SimonFrisendal/ae6880e68ce596a646b57444de6d1022)) which

1. Queries a realtime database ref (events) in the following fashion:

   `await admin.database().ref('/events_geo').once('value').then(snapshots => {`
2. Iterates through all the events

   `snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {`
3. Events are filtered by a criteria for further processing
4. Several queries are fired off towards realtime DB to get details related to the event

   `await database().ref("/ratings").orderByChild('fk_event').equalTo(snapshot.key).once('value').then(snapshots => {`
5. Data is prepared for SendGrid and the processing is finished

All of the data processing works perfectly fine but I can't get the outer await (point 1 in my list) to wait for the inner awaits (queries towards realtime DB) and thus when SendGrid should be called the data is empty. The data arrives a little while later. Example output from Firebase function logs can be seen below:

`10:54:12.642 AM Function execution started`

`10:54:13.945 AM There are no emails to be sent in afterEventHostMailGoodRating`

`10:54:14.048 AM There are no emails to be sent in afterEventHostMailBadRating`

`10:54:14.052 AM Function execution took 1412 ms, finished with status: 'ok'`

`10:54:14.148 AM <p style="margin: 1em 0px;">Super hyggelig aften :)</p><p style="margin: 1em 0px;">super oplevelse, ... long string generated`

[Gist showing the function in question](https://gist.github.com/SimonFrisendal/ae6880e68ce596a646b57444de6d1022)

I'm probably mixing up my async/awaits because of the awaits inside the await. But I don't see how else the code could be written without splitting it out into many atomic pieces but that would still require stitching a bunch of awaits together and make it harder to read.

So, two questions in total. Can this code work and what would be the ideal way to handle this pattern of making further processing on top of data fetched from Realtime DB?

Best regards, Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up refactoring the function as I realized it could be made much simpler thanks to Tarik Huber's answer.

The keypoints were:

1. to not use `forEach` and instead iterate using `for(const event of events)` as that is compatible with async calls
2. split the function into more modular parts. One part now fetches, filters and stores the data in an array. Second part iterates through the array and makes more async calls

This lead to more readable code that was also easier to debug.
The old function did both parts mentioned above in one go and wrongfully used `forEach` which lead to the issues with async calls not resolving properly.

An outline of the new function can be seen below. Only the important parts have been highlighted.

```
async function afterEventHostMail() {
 // Initialize variables
  events = [];

  await admin.database().ref('/events_geo').once('value').then(snapshots => {
    snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
      var event = snapshot.val();
      var eventKey = snapshot.key;
      
      // Do some filtering
      const mergedObj = { ...event, ...{ key: eventKey } };
      events.push(mergedObj)
    });
  });

  for (const event of events) {
    // Do a ton of await calls here
  }

  // The rest of the function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use `async` in a `foreEach` loop here:

```js
  Object.keys(event.participants).forEach(async (value: any) => {
```

The `forEach` loops don't support async calls. You need to map the data to an normal array and use a `for` loop. There you can use `await` normaly.

Comment: That was the missing piece. The fact that `forEach` don't support async calls lead me to refactor the entire function as there was also `snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {` which also lead into issues as I was revising the function. See my answer for a complete walkthrough of the refactoring.